# How do I sort alphabetically and lower case first

Tags: javascript

How do I get the result of the below sorting be `Food to Eat` then "FOOD 123".
Apparently, the 2nd lower 'o' should bring Food to Eat to the first item after sorting.

I'm surprised this question is not easy to find the answer by Google.
This feat is not included in the javascript standard is also surprising me.

```
[
"FOOD 123",
"Food to Eat"
].sort((a,b)=>{
    return a.localeCompare(b)
})



[
"FOOD 123",
"Food to Eat"
].sort()
```

[image]

Comment: note to help your research, this kind of feature is called "case sentitivity", "case sensitive search"

Comment: Odd, `[ "FOOD", "Food" ].sort((a,b)=> a.localeCompare(b))` sorts it "Food" -> "FOOD" correctly. However `[ "FOOD 1", "Food t" ].sort((a,b)=> a.localeCompare(b))` produces "FOOD 1" -> "Food t". [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ceximejecu/edit?js,console). So, the comparison takes the whole thing into account, for some reason, doesn't compare character by character. I played with the settings for localeCompare (and the Intl.Collators, as well) but doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: @VLAZ, actually `Intl.Collators` does not look predictable (to me).

Comment: @NinaScholz indeed, which is a problem. The `localeCompare` options should be making a collator implicitly but I tried it in isolation just in case. Also, by spec not all of the options given to a collator need to be respected. I was just surprised it seems to normalise the whole string, I was under the impression that it stopped at the first difference of characters. Apparently a custom sorter is indeed the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [`String.prototype.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) accepts options, that can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/Collator). `sensitivity: 'case'` should achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: [No, it doesn't work](https://jsbin.com/kexelakuje/edit?js,console). For some reason the whole string is considered, it doesn't stop at the first difference. I don't know why.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'd be stuck with writing your own sort method that sorts based on character code

Answer (score 1):

You could take a custom sorting approach and separate the characters into groups and then sort the strings of the temporary array.

```js
var array = ["FOOD 123", "Food to Eat", 'banana', 'Banana', 'BANANA'],
    result = array
        .map((string, index) => ({ index, value: Array.from(string, c => c === c.toLowerCase() ? ' ' + c : c + ' ').join('') }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value))
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);

console.log(result);
```