# localeCompare case-sensitive alphabetically issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve aAbBcC here. I tried en-US expecting to get desired result.
Expecting 'alpha' before 'Acuityads'.

```js
var array = [{name:"Acuityads"},{name:"alpha"}];

console.log(array.sort(function(a,b){return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, 
'en-US-u-kf-lower'); }));


console.log(array.sort(function(a,b){return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, 
'en-US'); }));

"alpha".localeCompare("Acuityads", 'en-US') // output as 1
```

Comment: you can specify also the sensitivity as option, please check the official doc on localecompare method

Comment: @quirimmo I did tried that also { sensitivity: 'base'/'case'} but didn't worked. variant is by default

Comment: also the locale can be used to specify it try as locale 'en-US-u-kf-lower'

Comment: yes, I have added that one in description. Not working for me.

Comment: Gone through this doc https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_localecompare.php

Comment: let me switch from laptop and take a look if you wont have any reply, that s weird you are not able to modify it  through either options nor locales

Comment: @quirimmo it's indeed weird - comparing "A" and "a" (one character only) works, the lowercase character is sorted first. However, if you have more characters, it bases the comparison on the rest, e.g., "ac" comes *after* "Ab". Not sure why that behaviour - the way I read the documentation suggests it should stop if two characters are considered different but it seems to not do that.

Comment: This linked question discusses the same topic, but doesn't have any good answers: [How do I sort alphabetically and lower case first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339482/how-do-i-sort-alphabetically-and-lower-case-first)

Comment: @Etheryte tried above not working for me https://codepen.io/rashmimhatre100/pen/gOwJpwv

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65842776/localecompare-case-sensitive-alphabetically-issue#comment116415145_65842776), this looks like an inconsistency either in the spec or the vendor implementation.
Since [an earlier question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339482/how-do-i-sort-alphabetically-and-lower-case-first) didn't have any answers I'd be happy to go with, here's [a manual implementation](https://www.karltarvas.com/2021/01/22/javascript-case-sensitive-string-compare.html):

```js
const input = ["aaaaa", "aaa", "aa", "aaaa", "aA", "Aa", "AA", "ab", "aB", "Ab", "AB"];

function caseSensitiveCompare(a, b) {
  // Sort character by character, return early if possible
  for (let ii = 0; ii < Math.max(a.length, b.length); ii++) {
    const aChar = a.charAt(ii);
    const bChar = b.charAt(ii);

    // If inputs match up to here, but lengths don't match, sort by length
    if (!(aChar && bChar)) {
      return a.length - b.length;
    }

    // If we meet a differing character, return early
    const comp = aChar.localeCompare(bChar);
    if (comp !== 0) {
      return comp;
    }
  }
  // If we found nothing to do, the strings are equal
  return 0;
}

console.log(input.sort(caseSensitiveCompare));
```

Comment: [I've found the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#collator-objects) but I can't locate what behaviour is expected for `caseFirst`. I've been skimming it, though. I'm actually interested in why this is happening, so I'll try to read it more in depth.

Comment: @Etheryte your manual implementation worked for me. Thanks a lot.